# Why am I getting a 404.3 error in IIS 8.0?

Tags: asp.net, windows-8, http-status-code-404, iis-8

So, I have actually been searching around Stack Overflow for about 20 minutes and still can't seen to find a definitive answer to my question.

I have had this error a few times, so I just did a fresh install of IIS 8.0 (I'm running Windows 8) and still got this error when I try to go to localhost/test1.aspx:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see (if you clicked the link), it is a 404.3 error.

Here are some of my details:

- I am running Windows 8
- I have IIS 8.0
- My physical directory is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test1.aspx`
- I am following a "W3Schools" tutorial correctly and I still can't get it to 
  work right
- I installed **every** feature that was available with IIS 8.0

Here is my source code for the "test1.aspx" file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<%
response.write("My first ASP script!")
%>
<body>
</html>
```

Anyone  have any answers for me please? They would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On Windows 8.1 you are using IIS 8.5, not 8.0, please change title, text and tags. Also remove the asp-classic tag and add asp.net unless you are really talking about classic asp.

Comment: o sorry I meant to put windows 8 not windows 8.1

Comment: Maybe your questions are poorly received because you confuse tech and don't follow posting rules, like for example not including "thanks" or signature lines. Also you mention `test1.aspx` which is a ASP.Net extension not Classic ASP which is completely different and years older.

Answer (score 3):

A 404.3 http status in IIS means that there is no MIME type defined for your file extension of `aspx`. You can also see in the error message that the StaticFileModule is handling the request. This is the module that serves static files from your hard drives.

It works correctly because it should not serve `*.aspx` files from the hard drive to the browser. You should not add a MIME type for `aspx`.

The problem is that the module that handles `aspx` files is not working correctly. There can be multiple reasons for this.

In IIS manager open your web site and double-click the `Handler Mappings` icon, there should be three entries for `*.aspx` (PageHandlerFactory).

Also make sure that the application pool for your site has a `.NET CLR Version` set.

If these properties are not set, there is a problem with your setup.

Comment: Please explain in simple form because I honestly do not understand what you said sorry but I am new programming.

Comment: sorry, that's as simple as I can be.

Comment: @AntiBullyingTaskForce You can't get much simpler then that.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry if you have tried this, but try this url entry: localhost/test1.asp

Ill add here, and please understand im not trying to be rude, that the reason you are not being well received is your questions are not really questions as such. The title of the post is what your question should be and just putting a '?' on the end of it doesn't make it a question. Basically it comes down to formatting the question correctly.

I.E. "IIS 8.0 404.3 error?" isn't a question nor does it give anything except something you could put into Google. Putting it this way might be better: "Why am I getting this a 404.3 error using ISS 8.0?"

Just some advice for next time :)

Comment: I understand that You are not trying to be rude but i said that some other Stackoverflow members have been harrassing me purposely(you cant see their comments anymore) and I meant to put "404.3" not "400.3" could you edit that please :)

Comment: To change the topic of the question itself you need to edit that or a moderator can.

Comment: nvm I did it myself but do you have a solution for my problem

Comment: ok, can you tell me the folder structure you have for the website. I.E. what did you put into the wwwroot folder?

Comment: I have all the regular IIS files(index.htm, etc.) in there PLUS the "test1.aspx" file that I made

Comment: Ok try this for me:

Create a new folder in the wwwroot folder names test and move the test1.asp file there.

After that open the browser again and type: "h t t p : //localhost/test/test1.asp" *remove the spaces from the http :// parts*

Comment: ok the only thing that i can think of that might be the cause is the way that ISS was setup initially.

Im guessing you are following the W3C Schools tutorial for ASP?

Comment: If you think this is the problem try explaining that `aspx` is not the same as `asp`. Plus if the OP is following the w3schools tutorials I'm not surprised they are struggling. Also what the heck is ISS? *International Space Station??*

Comment: Thanks for that pick up was doing a few other things at the same time lol corrected it. I believe they are following the W3Schools tutorial as the script is identical to theirs but having said that its only an assumption at this point, hence why i was seeking clarification.